# Fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory #include <iostream>

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I encountered a problem when I was learning C++, and encountered errors when I was compiling it.

The details are as follows:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try running a search for a file called `iostream` on your computer.
If the file doesn't exist that may mean the runtime library didn't get installed properly or not at all.

Comment: Specifically, does the file exist in C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\<your GCC version>\include\c++\ ? Also, do you have .cpp extension to your file (and NOT .c or something else)?

Comment: Also try entering only "C:\MinGW" as the compiler installation directory.

Comment: @mahesh Thx. The path in my system is C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include，there is no c++ in directory C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\<your GCC version>\include,and there is no iostream file in 'include'.
I have reinstalled MinGW，but it's still not there.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Thx. I have reinstalled MinGW，but it's still not there.

Comment: @mahesh,I have changed the dir to  "C:\MinGW",but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have not installed C++ support in MinGW. If you are using the manual installation route, download the gcc-c++ dev, dll, and bin files. If you are using the automated GUI installer (recommended for newcomer to C++), make sure to check the C++ package:
 [image]

Comment: I have reinstalled MinGW package.iostream file could be found in C:\MinGW\include\c++\3.4.5 ，but it show this build log when builded(Win 10 and CodeBlock):
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c D:\Coding\Cplus\HelloWorld\Chpt1Demo\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Chpt1Demo.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
D:\Coding\Cplus\HelloWorld\Chpt1Demo\main.cpp:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>

Comment: Can you try including the path C:\MinGW\include\c++\3.4.5 in the "Search directories" (for Compiler) in your project settings and try? Somehow the compiler is not able to find the installed file now.

Comment: ,I have included the path,and have get the messages:
||=== Build: Debug in Chpt1Demo (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\MinGW\include\c++\3.4.5\iostream|44|fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Does the file c++config.h exist in C:\MinGW\include\c++\3.4.5\bits\ ?

Comment: Yes,@mahesh，after I input the C:\MinGW\include\c++\3.4.5\bits\  ,it works ,but also give this message:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libstdc++.a(ios_init.o):ios_init.cc:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register' ... ...

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your MinGW installation or there are multiple installations on your machine. As a  last resort, remove all MinGW from your machine (including from system path) completely. Also remove Code::Blocks. Then install Code::Blocks with MinGW (codeblocks-17.12mingw-setup.exe). This will install Code::Blocks with its own MinGW with all right options.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not chosen C++ optional compiler/dev package in mingw32 installer. C++ dev package is not installed by default. Run the installer again and choose there required dev package for install.

> You can also add one or more of the following optional compilers or tools. For each you choose to install, you need **all three** of the *bin*, the *dev* and the *dll* component packages:
>
> - `gcc-c++` (*bin* and *dev* and *dll*) for C++