# "No such file or directory" error during C++ compilation

Tags: c++, compilation, codeblocks

> fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory

Why code blocks returned this error after compile

I'm a beginner in C++

Comment: It should be `#include <iostream>`

Comment: There is no `iostream.h` in C++.  If you learned C++ using TurboC++ then I regret to inform you that most of what you have learned is out of date and should pretty much be thrown out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iostream file not found in Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818958/iostream-file-not-found-in-codeblocks)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50504352/10957435

Comment: @Chipster Neither of those are correct.  This question is about missing `<iostream.h>` (which is an old non-standard header), not missing `<iostream>`

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah. Sorry. I knew I had seen something similar before and kind of just pounced.

Comment: Where is your code?!

Comment: Likely the Reverse-Duplicate: [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, You need to Include iostream without the 'h'

See More Information here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Comment: without the h it is `iostream.` :P

Comment: Better reference site: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream -cplusplus.com is generally a fairly poor reference..

Answer (score 0):

use only `#include<iostream>` as `#include<iostream.h>` works in old compiler like turbo c++.